# Displaying japanese characters in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cjk

Does anyone here have an idea how to work with japanese character in visual c++?

I'm trying to display a Japanese name in console with visual c++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "北島 美奈" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output in the console:

```
?? ??
Press any key to continue ...
```

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing multi-byte characters in terminal using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983906/printing-multi-byte-characters-in-terminal-using-c)

Comment: Did you try using L"", i.e. cout << L"北島 美奈" << endl;

Comment: @Nitesh, yes and the output is: 00057B30

Comment: Use wcout. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641718/how-to-output-unicode-characters-in-c-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of "Output unicode strings in Windows console app" 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app

Comment: also, make sure you have the font that supports that code page.

Comment: @codekaizer, how?

Comment: Still can't find any sample for displaying Japanese character.

Comment: Simple way to change a code page..type 'chcp 932' in the console window then execute your exe.

Comment: @tommybee, still the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with my own code both UTF-8 and EUC-KR(korean) on a console window using a cmd.exe.

This is my source code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int codepage = CP_ACP; //CP_ACP, CP_OEMCP
    int conv_codepage = CP_UTF8; //CP_UTF8
    char str[256];
    char str1[256];
    wchar_t tstr[256], tstr2[256];

    memset(str, 0x00, 256);
    memset(str1, 0x00, 256);
    memset(tstr, 0x00, 256);
    memset(tstr2, 0x00, 256);

    memcpy(str, " 北島 美奈", sizeof(str));

    int nLen = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, str, -1, 0, 0); 
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, str, -1, tstr, nLen);

    int len = WideCharToMultiByte( conv_codepage, 0, tstr, -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0 ); 
    WideCharToMultiByte(conv_codepage, 0, tstr, -1, str1, len ,0 ,0);

    cout << "2... " << str1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

case 1 UTF-8: the result on a console
The output is reasonable because the str1 variable is an utf-8 string.
I've got a correct utf-8 on a utf-8 console window.

[image]

case 2 EUC-KR: the result on a console
I think this case is also acceptable utf-8 string with a utf-8 string.

[image]

Then changing the code as follows

```
cout << "2... " << str << endl;
```

to

```
cout << "2... " << str1 << endl;
```

case 1 UTF-8: the result on a console
I think this is okey to me for an unicode string on a utf-8 console.

[image]

case 1 EUC-KR: the result on a console

It is still correct unicode string in a euc-kr codepage.

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and the output on my console is: 2...?? ??

Comment: Mine too, alas.

Comment: Okey, what happened with this simple code?  cout << "2... " << std::string(str)  << " \r\n"<< endl;

Comment: same here getting : 2...  ?? ??

Comment: @Arun Kumar what is your code page on cmd windows?  The command is 'chcp' in a cmd window...